# Python Syntax Error On The 5 In 3.5.1

Tags: python

When I try to run a python module it highlights the 5 in:

```
Python 3.**5**.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:38:48) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> print ("Hello")
```

and says it's "invalid syntax". I've seen other sites to try to fix it, but it gets *very* confusing. What am I doing wrong and why is it highlighting the 5 in 3.5.1?

Comment: how are you trying to "run the python module" ? also did you attend IDYCA last year?

Comment: Are you trying to execute that as if it were valid Python code, rather than a snippet of an interpreter session?

Comment: I'm going to the python module file I made, right clicking a module, and clicking Edit With IDLE, then clicking run

Comment: Well apparently that *"python module file"* doesn't contain syntactically valid Python code, instead containing a copied-and-pasted interpreter session. It's not clear why you anticipated that this would work.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to execute the introductory text the interpreter prints out when you start it as if it were actual, valid Python code. It's not clear why. To recreate:

```
$ python3 -c "Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:38:48)"
  File "<string>", line 1
    Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:38:48)
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here's how it's supposed to look:

```
$ python3  # I only typed this
Python 3.5.2 (default, Jun 29 2016, 13:43:58)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print ("Hello")  # and this
Hello
```

In this second, working case, I **start the interpreter**, which prints out a welcome message to tell me which version I'm running, and *then* start typing valid commands at the interpreter prompt.

Comment: how do I fix it though?

Comment: @Waffles what do you mean *"fix it"*? It's not clear what you expected to happen. Your Python file needs to contain **only valid Python code** (in this case just `print("Hello")`). I can only suggest following [a decent tutorial](http://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F).